# How to implement DbContext hierarchy

Tags: entity-framework

What I'd LIKE to do is manipulate EF to support plugins that access a shared database.  So the database would contain all of the tables for the main application plus all of the tables required for each plugin.  As the application doesn't know anything about the plugin data structures, it cannot be responsible for their management.  The plugins are solely responsible, and create the tables themselves.  However, the plugins know about the host application and its data structures, so ideally should be able to reference them and even inherit from them, resulting in a database that is extensible yet able to implement optimized patterns.

In EF, this translates to a HostContext that contains the DbSets appropriate for the Host.  Each Plugin, I thought, should have a PluginContext that inherits from HostContext that contains the DbSets needed by the plugin.  The entity classes included in PluginContext would then be able to reference HostContext entities, and/or inherit from those entities, and EF would be able to resolve the table mapping and relationships.

I'm using EF6.  When I attempt the above and try to list the single entity I've included in the PluginContext, an exception is thrown complaining that the entity doesn't exist. Sure enough, no matching table has been created.

Is what I'm attempting to do supported by EF?  If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned here: [EF6 Empty Model target string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952787/ef6-empty-model-target-string)
I began this effort using Rowan Miller's example here: http://romiller.com/2013/02/15/extending-and-customizing-code-first-models-part-2-of-2/

In the end, I abandoned that approach, for a few reasons: 1) I couldn't get it to work (I can't remember exactly why but I do suspect it was related to differences in EF since the article was written), and 2) I didn't like the need to write manual migrations.

I ended up with PluginContexts that inherit from HostContext, as I had hoped, and am able to reference and even inherit from host entities.  This has restrictions in its use though:

1. My plugin logic is completely self contained.  I have no need for the host application to manipulate or create plugin entities.  Therefore, I am not trying to get the system to subsitute any plugin entities for host entities.  If construction of a particular entity subclass is required, then a plugin method must be provided for that and an inheritence hiearchy will be utilized.
2. Migrations can be built even on the plugin context as per normal.  However, that migration may easily include migration code from the Host Context.  So I have to remember to look for and remove these instructions.  This is typically very straightforward and I believe is much less effort than building the equivalent from scratch.
3. If there is any change to the Host Context then this must be reflected in every Plugin Context.  Basically, this means anytime a new migration is created to reflect changes in Host Context, migrations must be created for each plugin as well, even  though that migration may be empty (it isn't really - the critical part here is updating the Model in the latest MigrationHistory record to reflect the Plugin model that has been changed because of the inherited Host model).

This approach is being used to extend an in-house application with in-house plugins, and so may not be as easy to adopt in other scenarios which Rowan's solution is probably better suited.