# EF6 Empty Model target string

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to get Rowan Miller's example to extend the model to work.  It is found here: http://romiller.com/2013/02/15/extending-and-customizing-code-first-models-part-2-of-2/

It doesn't quite work for me. The CustomizingMigration class, which derives DbMigration and implements IMigrationMetadata, provides a hard-coded string value for Target.  That value is supposed to represent an empty model.  I believe that the value of this string has changed since the example was posted.  I'd like to update that string but can't figure out how.

How can I generate a string representing an empty model?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing a completely different strategy for extending the database migrations and models whose approach is based on subclassing the context provided by the application API.  This is for internal use only, so may not accomplish some of the goals in Rowan's solution.

Anyways, the question was how to generate a string representing an empty model.  Turns out, this is pretty obvious if you're leveraging Migrations: simply create a migration from an empty model (using a DbContext with no DbSets), and look in the migration's resx for the Target value.